# Implementing inlineEventSelected on RadCalendarView

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

So i'm trying to implement a feature where when a user clicks on the inline event on the Rad Calendar, they are brought to a different page.

Im using NativeScript's TabView, so my app-component.ts file's template is an html page, which is why i believe im having these issues

//My app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/(home:home//assignments:assignments//history:history//help:help)", pathMatch: "full" },

{ path: "home", component: DashboardComponent, outlet: "home" },
{ path: "newJobView/:job/:location/:date/:shift/:position", component: ViewNewJobComponent, outlet: "home" },
{ path: "upcomingJobView/:job/:location/:date/:shift/:position", component: UpcomingJobViewComponent, outlet: "home"},

{ path: "assignments", component: JobsComponent, outlet: "assignments" },
{ path: "newJobView/:job/:location/:date/:shift/:position", component: ViewNewJobComponent, outlet: "assignments" },
{ path: "upcomingJobView/:job/:location/:date/:shift/:position", component: UpcomingJobViewComponent, outlet: "assignments"},
{ path: "pastJobView", component: UpcomingJobViewComponent, outlet: "assignments"},

{ path: "history", component: HistoryComponent, outlet: "history" },

{ path: "help", component: HelpComponent, outlet: "help" },

];
```

//My RadCalendar

```
<RadCalendar [eventSource]="eventSource" (dateSelected)="onDateSelected($event)" (inlineEventSelected) = "selectedDate($event)" eventsViewMode="Inline" row="0"inl></RadCalendar>
```

//My selectedDate() method:

```
selectedDate(args: CalendarDayViewEventSelectedData){
    this.router.navigate(["pastJobView"], {relativeTo: this.currentRoute});
}
```

Currently when i click on an inline event, i get this error message:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assignments/pastJobView'

Any ideas why i cant route to this page?

Comment: I believe you are using TabView, guessing you want to go to detail page on assignments tab in which case you should have `pastJobView` as a child route.

Comment: @Manoj Isnt that what i have in my app-routing.module? { path: "pastJobView", component: UpcomingJobViewComponent, outlet: "assignments"},